# Best way to display invalid login details message--django forms

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I want to display an error message to users along the lines of 'invalid username or password, please try again' for a login form in django if authentication fails, but im not sure what the best way to go about doing this is.
I've considered setting a context variable which will be passed into a template and then I could use CSS to present the message with the form. Something like below:

```
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                # Redirect to a success page.
            else:
                # Return a 'disabled account' error message
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            incorrect_login = True
            context = ('incorrect_login': incorrect_login, 'form':form)
            return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

And the html:

```
<form action="." method="POST"> {%csrf_token%}
  {%if incorrect_login%}
  <table class='failed_login'>
    {{form.as_table}}
  </table>
   {%else%}
  <table class='successful_login'>
    {{form.as_table}}
  </table>
  {%endif%}
  <p><input type='submit' value='Submit'></p>
</form> 
<!--Dont worry about the exact implementation of the html, its the basic idea im concerned with-->
```

However, I feel like this is a common problem and thus there is likely a better solution provided by django within the forms. I've looked into the docs on working with forms but im not sure how to approach, the main problem being that the errors stored in the form fields seem more about validating input type. Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Take look at django [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: The messages framework is great, but this *is* a form error, and should be shown in the context of the form. Forms can have both global errors and field errors. This seems like a global error that should appear at the top of the form, accessible via `form.errors` in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django comes with [built in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including one to log in. You should think about using the login view, or at least look at the code to see how it works.

One key thing is that a blank form is only created for `GET` requests. The problem in your view is that you always create a new form with `form = LoginForm()` when `user is None`. That means that the errors from the bound form (`form = LoginForm(request.POST)`) are not shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to share this approach with you, maybe it could help  :

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from ..form import UsersForm


class LoginView(View):

    template_name = ['yourappname/login.html', 'yourappname/home.html']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UsersForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, self.template_name[1], t)
        return render(request, self.template_name[0], t)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.is_active:
                return render(request, self.template_name[ 1 ])
        else:
            messages.add_message(
                request, messages.ERROR, "Incorrect user or password"
                )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse( 'yourappname:login' ))
```

As i see you already know the template interaction, sending by post the user and password and using django messages.
If you wish to manage the errors from the form you can use the clean method :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/